# AppleScript to mark video file as TV show?

Tags: itunes, video, applescript

I'm using Hazel to automate the conversion of video files to iTunes .mv4 format, however one limitation I've run into is being able to mark a video file as "TV show" or "Movie" before adding to iTunes.

I'd like to do this via Applescript so I can run it as part of my rule set up, but I'm more of an AppleScript copy/paster than a coder.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit to start the copy/pasting process, from the excellent "Doug's Scripts" website:

http://dougscripts.com/410

This is the "Set Video Kind of Selected" script, which lets you choose what kind you want the file to be marked as TV Show, Movie, etc.

Comment: I've looked at that AppleScript before, but it prompts the user to add info manually and I am looking to automate things. I think I may have deduced what I need to do, my earlier efforts were not calling iTunes in to set the video kind, will see if this works. Thanks!

Comment: @George: The script is free to anyone to modify. If you wish to work with Applescripts, at some point you need to learn to actually code rather than simple copying/pasting. You will get along a whole lot better with your Mac if you do. It is worth the effort.

Comment: @Philip I agree, I've tried to educate myself on AppleScript but the syntax just seems over my head. I'm more of a hobbyist and a reverse-engineerer.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from:

http://kjvarga.blogspot.ca/2009/03/applescript-automator-import-avi-video.html

```
on run {input, parameters}  
 set videoType to button returned of (display dialog ("What type of video are you importing?") buttons {"Movie", "TV Show"} default button {"TV Show"})  
 repeat with i in input  
  try  
   tell application "Finder" to set file type of file i to "MooV"  
  end try  
  tell application "iTunes"  
   set newAddition to (add (i as alias))  
   if videoType = "TV Show" then  
    tell newAddition to set video kind to TV show  
   end if  
  end tell  
 end repeat  
 return input  
end run
```

Answer (score 1):

1. open Automator
2. choose Application as Document type
3. select Run Applescript from the Utilities folder in the Automator Library
4. Paste this in to the part that says (*Your script goes here*)

   > tell application "iTunes"
   >   set newAddition to (add input)
   >   tell
   >   newAddition to set video kind to TV show
   >   end tell
5. Save with a useful name
6. Drop shows on the App and they will be added to iTunes as TV shows

Tested with iTunes 11

Comment: Can this be used within an AppleScript? I don't need to have the file actually added to iTunes, just marked as a TV show.

Answer (score 0):

Automator would be my first inclination if you don't want to learn the syntax and craft of making your own AppleScripts.

It lets you save an action as a service or as a folder action both of which are about as easy as a script. The service can run right out of iTunes if desired.

You can use several variables to try and fill in the TV related fields as well as just changing the media kind.

Comment: I was not able to find any Automator actions that allowed me to set the video kind for movie files. What is the name of the action I should be looking at? Thanks!

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21099/can-the-finder-edit-mp3-sound-file-tags-like-artist ( not at a mac so I'm not 100% sure the kind has a setter, but many fields are there )

Comment: Unfortunately that action only has tag fields for music/audio files.

Comment: That's less than ideal - unless someone makes or finds a plug in to teach Automator more tricks, you might be stuck scripting with other tools like shell or AppleScript.